# In upgrading from Craft 2 to Craft 3 I'm getting a SQL error saying the translationMethod column is missing

Tags: database, craft3, updating

The full message is:

```
Internal Server Error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
'fields.translationMethod' in 'field list' 
The SQL being executed was:     
SELECT fields.id, fields.dateCreated, fields.dateUpdated, fields.groupId,
fields.name, fields.handle, fields.context, fields.instructions,  
fields.translationMethod, fields.translationKeyFormat, fields.type, fields.settings 
FROM craft_fields fields WHERE fields.context='global'
ORDER BY fields.name
```

In looking at the database I only see the `translatable` column. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please send an email to support@craftcms.com with a pre-update attempt database backup as well as a zip of your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder so we can look into the error.

Comment: @BradBell sent.